# A local homeomorphism defined by linearly independent functions

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Consider a set of $n$ linearly independent functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$  i.e. $\{f_i:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\}_{i=1}^n$. These functions are homogeneous polynomials.

Using $\{f_i\}$ define a coordinate transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$   defined by 
$T(x) = (f_1(x), \cdots, f_n(x))$.

How to prove that $T(\cdot)$ is a local homeomorphism except possibly at some isolated points?.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $T(x,y)=(x^2,y)$ is not a local homeomorphism at all points $(x,0)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, and none of these points are isolated.

Comment: Dear @Eero Hakavuor many thanks for this counter example.